# Copy document to another collection with angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to copy the content of one document inside another collection, but i cant do it.
this is my code

first i get the reference with:

```typescript
this.pollRef = this.afs.collection('polls').doc(pollId);
```

then i try to copy it in another collection with this code :

```js
//Option 1 copy the documentRef
var idBefore = this.afs.createId();
console.log(idBefore);
const datas = { name: 'hola' }
this.afs.collection('rooms').doc(idBefore).set(datas);
var idBefore2 = this.afs.createId();
this.afs.collection('rooms')
        .doc(idBefore)
        .collection('poll')
        .doc(idBefore2)
        .set(this.pollRef);
```

it throw this error:

> ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid
>   data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom
>   AngularFirestoreDocument object

Answer (score 2):

Finaly i can resolve it. I share the answer to the comunity

```js
var idBefore = this.afs.createId();
    console.log(idBefore);
    const datas = { name: 'hola' }
    this.afs.collection('rooms').doc(idBefore).set(datas);
  
    var pollId: string = this.roomForm.get('pollId').value;
    const x = this.pollsService.getPoll(pollId);
    x.subscribe(poll => {
      //this.spinnerService.hide();
      const pollData = poll.payload.data() as Poll;
      pollData["id"] = pollId;
      this.PollModel = pollData;
      console.log(this.PollModel);
      this.afs.doc(`rooms/${idBefore}`).collection('polls').add(this.PollModel)
  
    });
```